# ios swift - dismiss root view controller of navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift

I'm opening a navigation controller from a button click of my main view controller.

I programatically created a left bar button item on the navigation controller which I want to dismiss the nav controller and go back to my main controller.

I'm essentially going back on the root view controller of the navigation controller.

I've tried

```
navigationController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

and

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

and get an NSException on both.

Please advise.

Comment: _What_ NSException do you get?

Comment: Are you pushing or presenting the `UIViewController`?

Comment: May be you're calling these method on `rootViewController` itself. what exception you are getting, BTW?

Comment: sounds more like a usecase for unwind segues: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561735/what-are-unwind-segues-for-and-how-do-you-use-them

Comment: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x154da4960
2016-03-17 19:16:29.363 [605:192637] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ back:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x154da4960'

Comment: how this was solved @Walking

Answer (score 9):

**Swift 3:**

```
self.view.window!.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
```

It will dismiss all the presented view controllers and remain root view controller.

Answer (score 4):

If you are **pushing** your `ViewController`, you should use **pop** to remove that `ViewController` from `Navigation` Stack and land on the previous `ViewController`. **Try this**...

```
self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true);
```

**SWIFT 3**

```
_ = navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true);
```

Answer (score 0):

dismissViewController works when you are showing a viewController using presentViewController, that maybe the root view controller of a navigation stack, or a stand alone view controller.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.presentingViewController?.presentingViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

Try this :)

Answer (score 0):

A year later.. The exception indicates that there is something wrong with the selector that you provide to the action param, when adding the left bar button.

Something like this should work:

creating bar button item:

```
let backBarButton = UIBarButtonItem.init(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.stop, target: self, action: #selector(dismissView))
```

dismiss root view controller:

```
func dismissView() {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apple Dev already provides very simple code which is

```
self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: false)
```